# Given a point and a line in homogeneous coordinates, what is the coordinate of the projection of the point on the line?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, matlab, homogeneous-spaces

Knowing $M$ and $L$ in homogeneous coordinates, how can we determine the coordinates of the point $P$?

[image: point projected onto line]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume the standard $z=1$ embedding, i.e. points homogenized as $(x,y)\mapsto[x:y:1]$ and line $[a:b:c]$ represents $ax+by+c=0$.

The coordinates $(a,b)$ represent the direction orthogonal to the line. $[a:b:0]$ is the point at infinity orthogonal to line $L$. You can connect that to $M$ to get the orthogonal line passing through $M$, and intersect that line with $L$ to get the orthogonal projection. Joining points and intersecting lines can both be expressed using the cross product.

$$P = ((F\cdot L)\times M)\times L\qquad\text{with }F=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

(If you are dealing with [Cayley-Klein metrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Klein_metric), $F$ would be the dual fundamental conic of the Euclidean plane, which is crucial for angle measurements, including the right angle used here.)

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! Could you please point me to an intuitive explanation of why the coordinates (a,b) represent the direction orthogonal to the line?

Comment: @NIM4: think about this in 3 dimensions. The line $L$ lies in your $z=1$ plane. All the homogeneous coordinate vectors incident with that line lie in a plane spanned by that line and the 3d origin. The vector $[a:b:c]$ representing the plane is orthogonal to all of them (zero scalar product) so it is the normal vector of that plane, original to it. And $[a:b:0]$ ist the component of that vector that lies within the $z=1$ drawing plane, the projection into that plane of you will.

Comment: @NIM4: another way to think about this: observe how the line $L$ intersects the line at infinity in $[b:-a:0]$. Rotating that point by $90°$ (around any center) results in $[a:b:0]$. If the former point indicated the parallel direction, the latter must indicate the orthogonal direction.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated!

Comment: it will still depends on what kind of projection is required; Given the constraints in the original post, it looks like an orthographic projection. both central projection and parallel projection (oblique or orthographic) are computation-friendly redefined as a common algebraic formula in Householder elemenetary matrix form: https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.0998

Answer (score 0):

it still depends on what kind of projection is required; Given the constraints in the original post, it looks like an orthographic parallel projection. Both `central projection` and `parallel projection` (oblique or orthographic) are computation-friendly redefined as a common algebraic formulation `equation 3.1` in Householder elemenetary matrix form this arXiv.org article: [Unified Framework of Elementary Geometric Transformation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.0998)

Suppose the homogeneous coordinates of the point $(x,y,1)^T$ and the line $(a,b,c)^T$; then an `orthographic parallel projection` onto the line $(a,b,c)^T$ uniquely determined by $(a,b,c)^T$ and its `normal direction` per `definition 3.6`, `definition 3.7` and `equation 3.1` (line No. 2 of table 1 in page 9) for 2D projective transformations in [Unified Framework of Elementary Geometric Transformation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.0998) has the following form:

$$\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]-\dfrac{\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 a \\
 b \\
 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]\cdot \left[a,b,c\right]}{\left[a,b,0\right]\cdot \left[
\begin{array}{c}
 a \\
 b \\
 c \\
\end{array}
\right]}
=\dfrac{1}{a^2+b^2}\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
 b^2 & -a b & -a c \\
 -a b & a^2 & -b c \\
 0 & 0 & a^2+b^2 \\
\end{array}
\right]$$

Then the orthographic parallel projection of $(x,y,1)^T$ onto the line $(a,b,c)^T$ is:
$$\dfrac{1}{a^2+b^2}\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
 b^2 & -a b & -a c \\
 -a b & a^2 & -b c \\
 0 & 0 & a^2+b^2 \\
\end{array}
\right]\cdot \left[
\begin{array}{c}
 x \\
 y \\
 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]= \dfrac{1}{a^2+b^2}\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 b^2 x-a b y-a c \\
 a^2 y-a b x-b c \\
 a^2+b^2 \\
\end{array}
\right]$$